# main() on the first place C

Tags: c, program-entry-point

So I have written this code and I wanted to ask is it possible to write main in the first place before other things?

```
#include <stdio.h>              // Standard Ein-/Ausgabefunktionen
#include <at89c51cc03.h>        // CC03er-Grundregister




#define CS_LCD  0xffb8

xdata unsigned char eak_io @0xff80;
xdata unsigned char DIS_IR_W @CS_LCD+0x0;
xdata unsigned char DIS_DR_W @CS_LCD+0x1;
xdata unsigned char DIS_IR_R @CS_LCD+0x2;
xdata unsigned char DIS_DR_D @CS_LCD+0x3;




void init_schnittstelle(void)
{
    SCON=0x52;                  // Initialisierung
    TMOD |=0x20;                // Timermodus 8-bit auto-reload
    TH1=0xfa;                   // 4800 Baud
    TR1=1;                  
}


void ms_warten(unsigned int multiplikator)
{
    unsigned int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<multiplikator;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<123;j++);
    }
}


void dis_ready(void)        
{
    while ((DIS_IR_R & 0x80)!=0);   
}



void init_lcd(void)         
{
    unsigned char i;

    for (i=0; i<=2; i++)
      {
        DIS_IR_W=0x30;
        ms_warten(10);
      }

    // Function Set: DL=1, N=1, F=0
    dis_ready();                  
    DIS_IR_W=0x38;

    // Display ON/OFF: D=1, C=1, B=0
    dis_ready();                   
    DIS_IR_W=0x0c;

    // Entry Mode Set: I/D=1, S=0
    dis_ready();                    
    DIS_IR_W=0x06;
}


void dis_clear(void)
{
    dis_ready();               
    DIS_IR_W=0x01;            
}


void dis_csr_set(unsigned char z, unsigned char s)
{
    unsigned char csr_pos;
    switch (z)                    
      {
        case 0 : csr_pos=s;         
             break;
        case 1 : csr_pos=s+0x40;   
             break;
        case 2 : csr_pos=s+0x14;  
             break;
        case 3 : csr_pos=s+0x54;   
             break;       }
    dis_ready();                    
    DIS_IR_W=(csr_pos | 0x80);    
}

void dis_text(unsigned char csr, unsigned char z, unsigned char s, char *a)
{
    unsigned char i;
    if (csr==1) dis_csr_set(z,s);  
    i=0;                           
    while(a[i]!=0)
      {
        dis_ready();                    
        DIS_DR_W=a[i];             
        i++;                       
      }
}


void main(void)
{
    char aktuellerWert;          
    init_schnittstelle();         
    init_lcd();                     
    while(1)
    {
        RI = 0;                    
        while(!RI);                
        if(SBUF != aktuellerWert) 
        {
            aktuellerWert = SBUF;  
            switch(aktuellerWert)     
            {

                case 'O':   dis_clear();     
                            dis_text(1, 1, 2, "blabla");
                            dis_text(1, 2, 1, "blabla");
                            dis_text(1, 3, 3, "blabla");
                            break;

                case 'G':   dis_clear();       
                            dis_text(1, 1, 2, "blabla");
                            dis_text(1, 2, 1, "blabla");
                            break;
                case 'R':   dis_clear();      
                            dis_text(1, 1, 2, "blabla");
                            dis_text(1, 2, 1, "blabla");
                            break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I would like to write main method before #define, o that it would be more or less in the first position.

Thanks!

Comment: Short of understanding what a *function prototype* is (hint for a web-search), i see nothing stopping you from doing this. (unrelated, `void main` is not standard. stop that).

Comment: Why don't you try it out? No, it wouldn't work because include just copies the files into your project and if you use a function out of these the function is at compile time not known, as it is farther down included

Comment: Try it, see if it compiles. If not, read the error message.

Comment: No since RI and SBUF would be undefined. You would probably be better off explaining why you would want to do such a thing if you want a good answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig OP seems to use C in a freestanding environment. The C standard does not specify how the program is started in such an environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler has to know just a few things about the functions that you use in your code before the are called. The actual implementation/definition of the function is not needed, only a declaration (a function prototype) is needed before calling. This can be done in two ways:

1. In a header file. Use this method if you want to use your functions in multiple C files.
2. Anywhere in the C source file (preferably in the beginning). These functions are limited to file scope, i.e. they are only available for use in the C source where they are  declared.

A function prototype looks like this:

```
return_type function_name(type_t param1, type_t param2);
```

For example:

```
int sum(int a, int b);
```

Would declare the function sum, telling the compiler that

1. A function named sum exists somewhere
2. The function takes two integers as parameters
3. The function returns an integer.

At this point, the compiler has no idea how the function is implemented. However, since the compiler knows that it exists and what it looks like, it will compile your code just fine.

Here is a short example using your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>              // Standard Ein-/Ausgabefunktionen
#include <at89c51cc03.h>        // CC03er-Grundregister

// Function prototypes for functions used in main() are here, now the compiler
// is aware of them

void init_schnittstelle(void); // Note the semicolon
void init_lcd(void);

// I didn't include the prototype for the function ms_warten(), since the main()
// Doesn't use it directly. Declatring it beforehand wouldn't hurt, though.

int main()
{
     // Your code here
}

#define CS_LCD  0xffb8 // This isn't used by main() either, so the compiler 
                       // doesn't needto know about it before the
                       // main() fucntion.

xdata unsigned char eak_io @0xff80;
xdata unsigned char DIS_IR_W @CS_LCD+0x0;
xdata unsigned char DIS_DR_W @CS_LCD+0x1;

void init_schnittstelle(void)
{
    // Your code here                 
}


void ms_warten(unsigned int multiplikator)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something called a *function declaration.* As opposed to a *function definition* like

```
int foo(int x)
{
    return x + 42;
}
```

which tells the compiler what a function does, a function declaration tells the compiler how to invoke a function. This would be a valid function declaration for `foo`:

```
int foo(int x);
```

Notice the lack of braces and the trailing semicolon. Declaring a function is sufficient for the compiler to know how to call it. So if you declare all the functions invoked by `main()` up front, you can define the main function first. Here is an example of what the might look like:

```
void init_schnittstelle(void);
void ms_warten(unsigned int multiplikator);
void dis_ready(void);
void init_lcd(void);
void dis_clear(void);
void dis_csr_set(unsigned char z, unsigned char s);
void dis_text(unsigned char csr, unsigned char z, unsigned char s, char *a);

void main(void)
{
    /* Code hier */
}
```

The customary order for the things in a program is this:

1. feature test macros
2. `#include` directives
3. `#define` directives
4. type and enumeration declarations
5. function declarations
6. variable definitions
7. function definitions

Notice that there is a bunch of stuff before you get to define `main()`, but you can still make `main()` the first function defined.